Is there a way to use this loop to return all values in this Excel file whilst performing the calculation in the code?
I am trying to figure out how to use the code I have written, specifically the loop section of the code to return all unique values in this excel file, but performing this calculation bu subtracting the years 2018 and 2021, just leaving the difference value next to the region and country columns.
I know that I have to use a loop in order to do this, but I am unsure of how best to go about it, I have tried different approaches, such as using a nested loop, but it just produces either duplicate or wrong values, and in some cases, the calculation doesn't even take place.
Here is an example of the data I am working with:
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['Austria', 'Austria', 'Ireland', 'Ireland'],
                   'REGION_2D': ['AT10', 'AT10', '4', '4'],
                   'value': [850.01874, 869.550869, 545.4036925, 560.695257],
                   'YEAR': [2018, 2021, 2018, 2021]})

Here is my code:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\blakecar\PycharmProjects\LFS Data\Mock File Population.xlsx", sheet_name='Sheet1')

df["COUNTRY"] = df["COUNTRY"].astype(pd.StringDtype())
df["REGION_2D"] = df["REGION_2D"].astype(pd.StringDtype())
df["Key"] = df["Key"].astype(pd.StringDtype())
df["Variable"] = df["Variable"].astype(pd.StringDtype())
df["variable_category"] = df["variable_category"].astype(pd.StringDtype())
df["YEAR"] = df["YEAR"].astype(pd.StringDtype())
print(df.dtypes)

#output dataframe to print the excel file to
output = pd.DataFrame()

output["COUNTRY"] = ""
output['REGION_2D'] = " "
output["Variable"] = ''
output['Key'] = ''
output["AC_Change"] = ''

def func1(geog):

    print("------------")
    print(geog)
    print("------------")
    filtered_df = df[df["COUNTRY"].isin([geog])]
    filtered_df = filtered_df[filtered_df["Variable"].isin(["people_15_64_W"])]
    #filtered_df = filtered_df[filtered_df["variable_category"].isin(['None'])]

    #filter through 2018 and summed it up
    filtered_2018 = filtered_df[filtered_df["YEAR"].isin(["2018"])]
    total_2018 = filtered_2018['value'].sum()
    #print(total_2018)
    #filter through 2021 and summed it up
    filtered_2021 = filtered_df[filtered_df["YEAR"].isin(["2021"])]
    total_2021 = filtered_2021['value'].sum()
    #print(total_2021)

    #AC change calculation
    total = total_2018 - total_2021
    #print(total)
    return total

#iterates through unique values- calls function should print to excel
geo = df['REGION_2D'].unique()
for geog in geo:
    funcValue1 = func1(geog)
    output.loc[len(output)] = {'REGION_2D': geog,'AC_Change': funcValue1}
#print(output)
output.to_excel('Mock File2.xlsx', index=False)

This is what I was hoping the expected output to look like:
| COUNTRY | REGION_2D | Value |
| -------- | -------- |
| Austria  |     1    |- 19.5321
| Ireland  |     4    |- 15.2916


In your expected output the values for "REGION_2D" make little sense. I trust you are simply looking for ['AT10', '4'] there, instead of [1, 4].

It's nearly always best to avoid loops with dfs. Here's one approach:
import pandas as pd

out = (
   df.pivot(index=['Country', 'REGION_2D'], columns='YEAR', values='value')
   .diff(periods=-1, axis=1)
   .rename(columns={2018: 'Value'})
   .dropna(axis=1)
   .reset_index()
   .rename_axis(columns=None)
   )

Output:
   Country REGION_2D      Value
0  Austria      AT10 -19.532129
1  Ireland         4 -15.291564

Explanation / Intermediates

Use df.pivot to reshape data.

# df.pivot(...)

YEAR                     2018        2021
Country REGION_2D                        
Austria AT10       850.018740  869.550869
Ireland 4          545.403693  560.695257


Get df.diff on axis=1 with periods=-1.

# df.diff(...)

YEAR                    2018  2021
Country REGION_2D                 
Austria AT10      -19.532129   NaN
Ireland 4         -15.291564   NaN


Values will now be in column 2018: apply df.rename to change label to "Value".
Use df.dropna to get rid of the empty column (2021).
Finally, apply df.reset_index to reset the index, and rename_axis to get rid of the columns name (i.e. YEAR).


Options if values need to be summed by "YEAR" first:

Via df.pivot_table with aggfunc='sum':

out = (
   df.pivot_table(index=['Country', 'REGION_2D'], columns='YEAR', 
                  values='value', aggfunc='sum')
   .diff(periods=-1, axis=1)
   .rename(columns={2018: 'Value'})
   .dropna(axis=1)
   .reset_index()
   .rename_axis(columns=None)
   )


Via pd.crosstab:

out2 = (
   pd.crosstab([df['Country'], df['REGION_2D']], df['YEAR'], 
               df['value'], aggfunc='sum')
   .diff(periods=-1, axis=1)
   .rename(columns={2018: 'Value'})
   .dropna(axis=1)
   .reset_index()
   .rename_axis(columns=None)
   )

out.equals(out2)
# True


Via df.groupby + df.unstack:

out3 = (
   df.groupby(['Country', 'REGION_2D', 'YEAR'])['value'].sum()
   .unstack(-1)
   .diff(periods=-1, axis=1)
   .rename(columns={2018: 'Value'})
   .dropna(axis=1)
   .reset_index()
   .rename_axis(columns=None)
   )

out2.equals(out3)
# True


It's hard to know exactly what questioner want, but assume from the code questioner provided, it looks like questioner want to apply a sum by year and then apply the difference, because unlike in questioner example, questioner data is not a single row per year, so it seems correct to use  pivot_table or groupby rather than pivot.

@PandaKim: yes, suppose that might be true, added that option. Thanks!

Your code seems mostly OK but you're mixing up COUNTRY and REGION_2D and using them interchangeably, which is causing your issues.
Try replacing:
geo = df['REGION_2D'].unique()

With:
geo = df['COUNTRY'].unique()

And you'll see sensible results.
Alternatively, you can replace:
filtered_df = df[df["COUNTRY"].isin([geog])]

with:
filtered_df = df[df["REGION_2D"].isin([geog])]

